# generate a list from a populated list

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have the below code:

```
        // If CheckBox is toggled, update the planet it is tagged with.
        checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
            Planet planet = (Planet) cb.getTag();
            planet.setChecked( cb.isChecked() );
            **ArrayList<String> FavList = new ArrayList<String>();
            FavList.add(planet.name);**
          }
        });        

  public void test (View view){
      Intent myintent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),     MultipleItemsList.class);
          myintent.putExtra("name", FavList);
          startActivity(myintent);
  }
}
```

What I want to do is add the checked planets to the "FavList" and then populate the list when a button is clicked. The method test is joined to a button, but I am getting the error FavList cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** You have **declared and initialized** the `FavList` inside the `Anonymous Inner Class` **scope**.

**2.** `Declare and Initialize` it at `Outer Class` **scope**, and to use it in the Inner class.

**3.** And if you are **Declaring and Initializing it in the method**, make it `final`, **so there can be an access to it from Inner class.**

Comment: It doesn't seem to initialise if i do it in the Outer class

Comment: Then just Declare it in Outer class...and initialize it in the inner class

Comment: It is working now thank you:) how do I save the checked items after the app restarts? Also, I want to delete the unchecked items from the list, where do I do that?

Comment: If you want to keep something which should be as it is after ur app restarts, then you need to persist the data, ie store it

Comment: Use Property file, use DataBase, Simple text file, etc

Comment: could you please give me some examples?

Comment: public class Test{ ArrayList<String> FavList = new ArrayList<String>();
checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
            Planet planet = (Planet) cb.getTag();
            planet.setChecked( cb.isChecked() );
            FavList.add(planet.name);**
          }
        });

Comment: I don't get how that snippet is different from adding the item to the FavList

Comment: I am declaring (and also initializing)the Favlist in the Class scope, rather than the Inner class scope, so the test() method now can see the Favlist. Normally declaration would hve been enough...but still i did it..

Comment: I am at office now... so can't come to chat now...we can do it later..is that ok with u ?

Comment: i think you are still answering the original question, i need help storing the values to load onCreate();

Answer (score 1):

It's because you defined `FavList` inside a local scope. It's unknown in `test` method therefore you are getting the error FavList cannot be resolved to a variable.

Defining `FavList` globally and initializing it in the same line (`FavList = new ArrayList<String>();`)  would fix this.

Comment: I tried to define it globally and it wasn't recognised as the  above snippet is in a custom adapter.